# Mapstruct Kotlin Gradle - Interface Implementation are not complete

Tags: kotlin, mapstruct, gradle-kotlin-dsl

-Entity Definition

```
@entity
data class Customer(
@id @GeneratedValue
var id: UUID? = null,
@column(columnDefinition = "text")
val name: String,
@column(columnDefinition = "text")
val phoneNo: String,
val dateOfBirth: LocalDate,
val customerSince: LocalDate,
@column(columnDefinition = "timestamp default current timestamp")
val lastUpdatedAt: LocalDateTime,
@OnetoOne
val address: Address,
@OnetoOne
val paymentInfo: PaymentInfo
)
```

-Mapping definition

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
interface CustomerMapper {
@mapping(source = "id", target = "customerId")
fun toCustomerDto(customer: Customer): CustomerDto

@InheritInverseConfiguration
fun toCustomer(customerDto: CustomerDto): Customer
}
```

-Generated Code

```
@generated(
value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
date = "2021-07-13T21:56:38-0600",
comments = "version: 1.4.2.Final, compiler: IncrementalProcessingEnvironment from kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle-1.5.20.jar, environment: Java 11.0.10 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@component
public class CustomerMapperImpl implements CustomerMapper {

@Override
public CustomerDto toCustomerDto(Customer customer) {
    if ( customer == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    UUID customerId = null;
    String name = null;
    String phoneNo = null;
    LocalDate dateOfBirth = null;
    LocalDate customerSince = null;
    LocalDateTime lastUpdatedAt = null;
    AddressDto address = null;
    PaymentInfoDto paymentInfo = null;

    customerId = customer.getId();
    name = customer.getName();
    phoneNo = customer.getPhoneNo();
    dateOfBirth = customer.getDateOfBirth();
    customerSince = customer.getCustomerSince();
    lastUpdatedAt = customer.getLastUpdatedAt();
    address = addressToAddressDto( customer.getAddress() );
    paymentInfo = paymentInfoToPaymentInfoDto( customer.getPaymentInfo() );

    CustomerDto customerDto = new CustomerDto( customerId, name, phoneNo, dateOfBirth, customerSince, lastUpdatedAt, address, paymentInfo );

    return customerDto;
}

@Override
public Customer toCustomer(CustomerDto customerDto) {
    if ( customerDto == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    Customer customer = new Customer();

    customer.setId( customerDto.getCustomerId() );

    return customer;
}

protected AddressDto addressToAddressDto(Address address) {
    if ( address == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    int streetNo = 0;
    String streetName = null;
    String city = null;
    String state = null;
    int zip = 0;

    streetNo = address.getStreetNo();
    streetName = address.getStreetName();
    city = address.getCity();
    state = address.getState();
    zip = address.getZip();

    AddressDto addressDto = new AddressDto( streetNo, streetName, city, state, zip );

    return addressDto;
}

protected PaymentInfoDto paymentInfoToPaymentInfoDto(PaymentInfo paymentInfo) {
    if ( paymentInfo == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    String creditCard = null;
    int expiryMonth = 0;
    int expiryYear = 0;
    int cvv = 0;

    creditCard = paymentInfo.getCreditCard();
    expiryMonth = paymentInfo.getExpiryMonth();
    expiryYear = paymentInfo.getExpiryYear();
    cvv = paymentInfo.getCvv();

    PaymentInfoDto paymentInfoDto = new PaymentInfoDto( creditCard, expiryMonth, expiryYear, cvv );

    return paymentInfoDto;
}
}
```

-Gradle build script
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

```
plugins {
id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.2"
id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.20"
kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.20"
kotlin("kapt") version "1.5.20"
kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.5.20"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final")
kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType {
kotlinOptions {
freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
jvmTarget = "11"
}
}

tasks.withType {
useJUnitPlatform()
}

kapt {
arguments {

arg("mapstruct.defaultComponentModel", "spring")
}
}
```

-Problem:
Though Mapstruct is generating the code for the function toCustomer, the implementation is broken as properties of Customer are not set except for the id field. What needs to be done so that all interfaces are implemented properly. There is a related issue on mapstruct with Kotlin & Gradle that results are not consistent, sometimes code is generated and sometime its not, experienced by me as well https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2499

Answer (score 0):

The problem here has nothing to do with Gradle and everything to do with the way the Kotlin data class is defined.

I am not an expert in Kotlin.

However, when you use `val` in Data classes Kotlin will generate a number of constructors including the default empty constructor. Since we currently cannot easily detect whether a class is a Kotlin data class during the annotation processing MapStruct picks the wrong constructor to perform the mapping.

There is already an issue reported for this and can be found [here](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2281)

Comment: Are there any workarounds/hacks to solve this problem at the moment? I don't see the issue is prioritized yet.

Comment: If you can force an annotation on one of the constructors then annotating it with `@Default` from any package should work

Comment: @SarangKanabargi did you manage to find a solution for this? @Filip, using the `@Default` annotation on the constructor worked prior to Kotlin v1.5+, but it's not working anymore